# changing font size of div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios

I want to change the font size with jquery if I'm using an iphone.  I start in the style section  in the head with

## txtArea {font-size:30px}

I have the following code in the body 
      if ($(window).width() < 600) { $('#txtArea').css('font-size', '60px');}

However, on the iphone the text stays small.  Any idea what could cause this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you placed your `<script>` element before the `#txtArea` element, the code will not find the element --- and therefore will not do anything.

You should wrap your code in a document ready handler like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
        $('#txtArea').css('font-size', '60px');
    }
});
</script>
```

Then the code will not execute until after the `#txtArea` element exists.